# Query orientDB in R, how to tune the query?

Tags: r, orientdb

I use R to query OrientDB using RJDBC library, my database has two node classes:

```
persons--visits-->places
```

places has 1.5 million records, persons have 4 million records, and the number of edge is around 4 million, even the simple query like

```
dbGetQuery(conn, "select ID from places")
```

Takes about 90 secs (PostgreSQL takes less than 30 secs), and the following query take about 20 minutes

```
dbGetQuery(conn, "select ID, in('visits').Name[0] as singleVisitor from places")
```

How to speed up the second query? Where is the bottleneck of the performance? OrientDB JDBC driver? Or OrientDB or R?

Comment: Are you really interested on downloading the entire 1.5M places as records with one query?

Comment: yes, for some reason. @Lvca.